# Move value from one attribute to another

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a wrapper for D3 which generates a graph with axis labels placed using x/y attributes, which makes them very hard to rotate correctly. I'd like to change the behaviour without editing the library I'm using.

I'd like to transform:

```
<text x="690" y="344" dy="12" style="text-anchor: middle;">foo</text>
```

into:

```
<text dy="12" style="text-anchor: end;" transform="translate(690,344) rotate(90)">foo</text>
```

I've got the right selector and can change the static parts, but how do I reference one attribute from another in this case?

```
chart.selectAll('g.cols.axis text')
  .attr('x', null)
  .attr('y', null)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(?,?) rotate(90)')
```

How can I get the x/y values copied into the translate part?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way of doing this is to change the order of the method calls. You start erasing the attributes by providing `null` to the setters and, hence, making them unavailable when you need them to set the translation values. You could just reorder your calls to first set the transformation which has the `x` and `y` attributes still available and remove those attributes afterwards.

```js
d3.select("svg").selectAll('text')
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr('transform', function() {
     let elem = d3.select(this);
     return `translate(${elem.attr("x")},${elem.attr("y")}) rotate(90)`;
  })
  .attr('x', null)
  .attr('y', null);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<svg>
  <text x="60" y="30" dy="12" style="text-anchor: middle;">foo</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think not chaining might do it.

```
const elements = chart.selectAll('g.cols.axis text');

// Get the values 
const xValue = elements.attr('x');
const yValue = elements.attr('y');

elements.attr('x', null)
  .attr('y', null)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr('transform', `translate(${xValue},${yValue}) rotate(90)`);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't quite work. The x value is the first one available, the y value is just null afterwards: `<text> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(32,null) rotate(90)".` for each entry :(